# Only content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains content controls

Tags: asp.net

only content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains content
and it is showing  red color error..

i am getting the  above error after publish the  web site in iis  in source code it is not showing any error but in iis  it is giving the error.

and one more thing is  in local server(iis) and  source code no problem but in client  iis the above problem is comming

i have  25  forms  out of 25  forms   only 3  are giving the same problem ...
i am getting  master page  from each form..
Can u plz give me any suggesions..
plz..

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have written Script tag or some other contents outside the  tags. Remove it from outside and put it inside the tags. Your error could be gone.

Thanks.

Comment: hi Monika can u plz have a look on below link  i added  my code in notepad http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/469114/leave-txt.html plz give me suggestions

Comment: @SrinivasRachumallu this file is perfect can u also check other 3 files which gives error.

Comment: hi monika thanks for your reply..http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/469117/profile-txt.html actually  previous links i given na that  form also  giving the error this is  another form design code  this form also giving the same error can u plz check it

Comment: Remove <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<title></title></html> from your page as you are using master page. Try out. Keep only <script></script> tag.

Comment: http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/469123/APPRO-txt.html this is my last form  i think  same problem  like above what u given suggestion but plz have a look on above code..

Comment: From here also remove the same thing as i told in previous comment

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage1.master" AutoEventWireup="false"
    CodeFile="App_form.aspx.vb" Inherits="App_form" Title="Untitled Page" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">

    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server" Style="z-index: 100; left: 757px;
        position: absolute; top: 434px; height: 15px; width: 77px;" Font-Bold="True"
        Font-Names="Times New Roman" Font-Size="Medium" Visible="false">LogOut</asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" 
    Font-Names="Cambria" Font-Size="Large"
        Style="z-index: 102; left: 0px; position: absolute; top: -1px; width: 1125px;
        text-align: center; height: 25px;" Text="Appraisal Form" BorderColor="#8CB1DA" 
        ForeColor="Black" BackColor="#666666"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Style="top: 57px; z-index: 103;
        left: 9px; position: absolute; height: 275px; width: 1111px;">
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Cambria" ForeColor="Black"
            Style="z-index: 100; left: 10px; position: absolute; top: 38px; width: 107px;"
            Text="Employee Code" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDepartment" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Cambria"
            ForeColor="#0000C0" Style="z-index: 101; left: 348px; position: absolute; top: 63px;
            width: 135px; bottom: 193px;"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesignation" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Cambria"
            ForeColor="#0000C0" Style="z-index: 101; left: 119px; position: absolute; top: 63px;
            width: 134px;"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtemp" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Cambria"
            ForeColor="#0000C0" Style="z-index: 101; left: 120px; position: absolute; top: 37px;
            width: 133px;"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Cambria" ForeColor="Black"
            Style="z-index: 102; left: 264px; position: absolute; top: 37px; width: 66px;"
            Text="Name" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Cambria"
            ForeColor="#0000C0" Style="z-index: 103; left: 349px; position: absolute; top: 37px;
            width: 135px;"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Cambria" ForeColor="Black"
            Style="z-index: 104; left: 8px; position: absolute; top: 89px; height: 20px;
            bottom: 166px;" Text="Date of Join" Width="107px" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtdt" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Cambria"
            ForeColor="#0000C0" Style="z-index: 105; left: 119px; position: absolute; top: 89px;
            width: 135px;"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Cambria" ForeColor="Black"
            Style="z-index: 106; left: 492px; position: absolute; top: 38px; width: 81px;"
            Text="Designation" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtpos" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Cambria"
            ForeColor="#0000C0" Style="z-index: 107; left: 575px; position: absolute; top: 37px;
            width: 135px;"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblReviewer" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Cambria"
            Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Black" Style="z-index: 100; left: 493px; position: absolute;
            top: 89px; width: 77px;" Text="Reviewer"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="lblLocation" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Cambria"
            Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Black" Style="z-index: 100; left: 264px; position: absolute;
            top: 87px; width: 72px;" Text="Location"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="lblDepartment" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Cambria"
            Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Black" Style="z-index: 100; left: 262px; position: absolute;
            top: 60px; width: 81px;" Text="Department"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="lblManager" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Cambria"
            Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Black" Style="z-index: 100; left: 10px; position: absolute;
            top: 65px" Text="Manager" Width="107px"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Cambria" ForeColor="Black"
            Style="z-index: 109; left: 494px; position: absolute; top: 62px; width: 47px;"
            Text="Grade" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
        &nbsp;
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Font-Bold="True"
            Font-Names="Cambria" ForeColor="#0000C0" Style="z-index: 110; left: 119px;
            position: absolute; top: -30px; width: 130px;">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Cambria" ForeColor="#0000C0" Style="z-index: 110; left: 574px;
            position: absolute; top: 62px; width: 136px; height: 19px;">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <div id="divGV" style="overflow: scroll; height: 150px; width: 100;">
            <asp:Label ID="Label19" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Cambria"
                Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Black" Style="z-index: 103; left: 265px; position: absolute;
                top: -32px; height: 29px; width: 446px;"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="Label18" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" 
                Font-Names="Cambria" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Black" Style="z-index: 103; left: 7px; position: absolute;
                top: -32px; height: 29px; width: 104px;" Text="Document No"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" 
                Font-Names="Cambria" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Black" Style="z-index: 103; left: 11px; position: absolute;
                top: 5px; height: 29px; width: 92px;" Text="From Month"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Cambria"
                Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Black" Style="z-index: 103; left: 323px; position: absolute;
                top: 5px; height: 29px; width: 84px;" Text="To Month"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txttyear" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Cambria"
                ForeColor="#0000C0" Style="z-index: 108; left: 528px; position: absolute; top: 5px;
                width: 61px; right: 126px; height: 19px;" TabIndex="5"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtfyear" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Cambria"
                ForeColor="#0000C0" Style="z-index: 108; left: 253px; position: absolute; top: 7px;
                width: 61px; right: 797px;" TabIndex="5"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txttmonth" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Cambria"
                ForeColor="#0000C0" Style="z-index: 108; left: 401px; position: absolute; top: 7px;
                width: 55px; right: 259px;" TabIndex="5"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Label ID="lblFrmYear" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Cambria"
                Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Black" Style="z-index: 102; left: 167px; position: absolute;
                top: 6px; right: 864px; width: 80px; height: 22px;" Text="From Year"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Cambria"
                Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Black" Style="z-index: 103; left: 467px; position: absolute;
                top: 5px; height: 21px; width: 83px;" Text="To Year"></asp:Label>
            <asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" ShowFooter="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            OnRowDeleting="OnRowDeleting" 
                Height="28px" Width="705px" BackColor="#666666" BorderColor="#666666" 
                CellPadding="2" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="None" Font-Names="Cambria" 
                Font-Size="Small">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="S.No" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Key Results Area">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="KPI">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Target">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Weightage(%)">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Target Achieved (Self-Assessment)">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <%-- <asp:DropDownList ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Width="150" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Enabled="false">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="-- Select --" Value="-1" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Needs Improvements" Value="Needs Improvements" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Party Meets Expectation" Value="Party Meets Expectation" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Meets Expectation" Value="Meets Expectation" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Sometime Exceeds Expected" Value="Sometime Exceeds Expected" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="OutStandaing" Value="OutStandaing" />
                            </asp:DropDownList>--%>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remarks">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Target Achieved (Appraiser)">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Final Achievement.">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reviewer's Comment">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Row" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click" />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Delete" HeaderText="Delete" 
                        ShowHeader="True" Text="Delete"  />
                </Columns>
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#666666" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" ForeColor="DarkSlateBlue" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="DarkSlateBlue" ForeColor="GhostWhite" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#666666" Font-Bold="True" />
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtfmonth" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Times New Roman"
            ForeColor="#0000C0" Style="z-index: 120; left: 108px; position: absolute; top: 7px;
            height: 19px; width: 51px;" TabIndex="4"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtReviewer" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Cambria"
            ForeColor="#0000C0" Style="z-index: 101; left: 574px; position: absolute; top: 90px;
            width: 135px;"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLocation" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Cambria"
            ForeColor="#0000C0" Style="z-index: 101; left: 348px; position: absolute; top: 89px;
            width: 135px;"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnProcess" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Cambria"
            Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="White" Style="z-index: 111; left: 611px; position: absolute;
            top: 4px; height: 22px; width: 96px;" Text="Process" ValidationGroup="add" 
            BackColor="#666666" BorderColor="Blue" BorderStyle="Solid" />
        <asp:Button ID="add" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Cambria"
            Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="White" Style="z-index: 111; left: 557px; position: absolute;
            top: 400px; height: 26px; width: 66px;" Text="Submit" 
            ValidationGroup="add" BackColor="#666666" BorderColor="Blue" 
            BorderStyle="Solid" />
        <asp:Button ID="cancel" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Times New Roman"
            Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="White" Style="z-index: 113; left: 628px; position: absolute;
            top: 400px; height: 26px; width: 66px;" Text="Cancel" BackColor="#666666" 
            BorderColor="Blue" BorderStyle="Solid" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" AlternateText="Add" BorderStyle="None"
            ImageUrl="~/Images/btn.jpeg" Style="z-index: 114; left: 661px; position: absolute;
            top: 96px; height: 17px; width: 50px;" Visible="False" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAppraiser0" runat="server" Style="z-index: 170; left: 201px;
            position: absolute; top: 360px; width: 493px; height: 32px;" 
            TextMode="MultiLine" Font-Names="Cambria"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAppraiser" runat="server" Style="z-index: 170; left: 201px; position: absolute;
            top: 323px; width: 493px; height: 31px;" TextMode="MultiLine" 
            Font-Names="Cambria"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTraining" runat="server" Style="z-index: 170; left: 201px; position: absolute;
            top: 287px; width: 493px; height: 30px;" TextMode="MultiLine" 
            Font-Names="Cambria"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Cambria" Font-Size="Medium"
            ForeColor="Black" Style="z-index: 109; left: 13px; position: absolute; top: 362px;
            width: 179px; height: 24px;" Text="Final Comments - Reviewer"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Cambria" Font-Size="Medium"
            ForeColor="Black" Style="z-index: 109; left: 12px; position: absolute; top: 326px;
            width: 189px; height: 25px;" Text="Final Comments - Appraiser"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Cambria" Font-Size="Medium"
            ForeColor="Black" Style="z-index: 109; left: 14px; position: absolute; top: 290px;
            width: 131px; height: 21px;" Text="Training Needs"></asp:Label>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvApprList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="#DEBA84"
            BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2"
            Height="174px" Width="729px" DataKeyNames="DocEntry">
            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Link" Text="Select" CommandName="SLK" HeaderText="Select"
                    ItemStyle-Font-Bold="true" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-ForeColor="DarkBlue" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DocEntry" HeaderText="Doc Entry" ItemStyle-Font-Bold="true"
                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" Visible="false"/>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="U_NAME" HeaderText="Employee Name" ItemStyle-Font-Bold="true"
                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="U_DSIG" HeaderText="Designation" ItemStyle-Font-Bold="true"
                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="U_FrmMth" HeaderText="From Month" ItemStyle-Font-Bold="true"
                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="U_FrmYer" HeaderText="From Year" ItemStyle-Font-Bold="true"
                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="U_ToMth" HeaderText="To Month" ItemStyle-Font-Bold="true"
                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="U_ToYer" HeaderText="To Year" ItemStyle-Font-Bold="true"
                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
            <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

Put this code.

Comment: OK  GIVE ME SOME TIME I WILL  MAKE CHANGES  AND  I WILL TEST IT HERE THANK YOU I WILL CHECK IT..

Comment: hi monica  the above code  i tried ... local iis working fine but  client server  not working same error is comming like previoushttp://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/469130/Errror-JPG.html have a look on above  image

Comment: hi any body help me ..Actually  what is the problem.. is there any iis  problem in client..